# When an Express.js middleware modifies the chunk that goes into res.end(), response times go up by 10x

Tags: node.js, express

Node.js version: 14.16, Express version: 4.17

We use `express-winston` for logging our express responses. Since we want additional information to go into our logs, that we don't want our end-users to see, we decided to include a middleware that wraps `res.end()`, so as to intercept the chunk sent by `express-winston`, and remove the additional data.

For reference here's the line of code in `express-winston` that calls `res.end()`, whose chunk we want to replace before the response is sent to the end-user, without altering the chunk that is logged:

https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston/blob/bdba1d39965f83b003178646d213cd974b090326/index.js#L317

Here is a sample middleware that we wrote:

```
module.exports.responseMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const { end } = res;
  res.end = (chunk, encoding) => {
    res.end = end;
    // If alterBody is enabled, the chunk sent to res.end is modified
    const resultChunk = req.body.alterBody === 'yes'
      ? Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({}))
      : chunk;
    res.end(resultChunk, encoding);
  };
  next();
};
```

The original response is sent with a call to `res.status(...).json(...)`

What we found was that when we enable `alterBody`, the response time goes up by 10x (from 500ms to 5s).

What could be the reason for this? Is there a way that we can maintain the original response time, while also logging and sending two different chunks?